# Showing date in MM/DD/YY format in a gridview column from .cs page/rowdatabound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, grid, dataset

I am getting a date time field from database with timestamp.

My grid has an auto-generated column.

I am formatting it in my `.cs` page

```
dsWorkItems.Tables[0].Rows[count]["Date"] =
                    !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dsWorkItems.Tables[0].Rows[count]["Date"].ToString()) ?
                    ((DateTime)(dsWorkItems.Tables[0].Rows[count]["Date"])).ToShortDateString(): "";
```

In quick watch I am getting

```
((DateTime)(dsWorkItems.Tables[0].Rows[count]["Date"])).ToShortDateString() as 9/26/2013
```

but in grid I am getting `9/26/2013 12:00:00 AM` but I want to show in grid `9/26/13`

And one more thing is it possible to show the full datetimestamp value from database in cell tooltip..

I have tried

```
 dsWorkItems.Tables[0].Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yy";
```

but DefaultCellStyle assembly missing i added System.Windows.Form but still not worked

Comment: You show two different columns, the one you are changing seems to be a string column with name `Date`, the other `DateTime` column shown in the grid is `MODIFIED`. That's confusing, please clarify.

Comment: Sorry My bad..i am modifying it.  it just killing me ..

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**: In aspx page.

The best thing to do in this case that I prefer to do is:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Modified" DataFormatString="{0:d}" 
   HeaderText="Modified On" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7"></asp:BoundField>
```

and set the `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` in the gridview.

Use `BoundField` for all the columns.

**Method 2**: In Codebehind have a row-databound event for your grid and perform the necessary
formatting like this:

```
date1.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I dont have bounded field dude :(

Comment: Grid must be getting the fields from binding data from code-behind. Setting auto-generate columns to false allows u to use boundfield. Else you can always use the row-databound event.  

"I am getting a date time field from database with timestamp.
My grid has an auto-generated column."

Comment: Can u gave an example how to do it in rowdatabound

Comment: e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 2].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 2].Text.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yy")

Comment: the above did the trick for me...but thanks for your help really helpful...cheers.