# How To Remove Time From DateTime When Pulling From Database Using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I've got a database table hosted on SQL Server.

The issue is with a column, which is of 'date' type. When pulling from the database using my stored procedure the date is displayed with the time 12:00:00 AM appended to it.

For example the date '30/10/2015' will be stored in the database as solely the date, but when it's added to the gridview, as mentioned above, the time 12:00:00AM is appended to it. I solely want the date to be displayed in the gridview, not the time.

Here is the code that binds the data from the database to the gridview:

```
private void BindGridEvent()
{
    string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManage.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EventInfo_CRUD"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView2.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the stored procedure used to pull the data from the database:

```
[dbo].[EventInfo_CRUD]
      @Action VARCHAR(10)
      ,@EventID INT = NULL
      ,@Location nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
      ,@EventName nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
      ,@EventDescription nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
      ,@EventDate date = NULL
      ,@EventTime time = NULL
      ,@ImageUrl nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --SELECT
    IF @Action = 'SELECT'
    BEGIN
        SELECT 
            EventID,Location, EventName, EventDescription, 
            EventDate, EventTime, ImageUrl
        FROM EventInformation
    END
```

Help would be much appreciated guys! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045385/showing-date-in-mm-dd-yy-format-in-a-gridview-column-from-cs-page-rowdatabound

Comment: This is a formatting issue.  There is no `Date` type in C#, only `DateTime` so if you don't want to show the time you need to change your format in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works for me when i need to format a DateTime Column in my gridview

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="TRANDATE" HeaderText="Document Date" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Try this for template field:

```
<%# Bind("Document Date", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention. The column is a TemplateField not a BoundField :( Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! That fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to instruct the gridview - or more precisely: one of it's `BoundField` column types - to display this .NET `DateTime` in a specific format - only showing the date portion, no time.

This means you need to add your columns to your gridview manually - you cannot use `AutoGenerateColumns` on the gridview.

Then, for those columns in question, you need to set the `DataFormatString` property something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ......>
    <Columns>  
        .......
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EventDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />

        .......
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView ......>
```

The `{0:d}` formatting string instructs .NET to display the "short date format" for this `DateTime` which basically is just year, month and day in whatever your default date formatting style is.

See the [MSDN documentation on the `DataFormatString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details about all the various options you have

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have not shown my ASP code.

That would most certainly work if my column was a BoundField, but it is a TemplateField. I have an ItemTemplate within my templateField, so changing it to a BoundField throws the error "Validation (HTML5): Element "ItemTemplate" is not supported."

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `asp:TemplateField`, try this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="EventDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EventDate ", "{0:d}") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thank you sir that fixed it finally!